# Why do I keep getting a CORS error whilst trying to perform a Google Sign-In Using ExpressJS and ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, passport.js

I'm using ReactJS, NodeJS, ExpressJS and PassportJS. I'm trying to have the user perform a single sign in.

The front end looks like this. This is the function that gets called when the user clicks the login button.

```
handleLogin() {
axios.get('http://localhost:8080/api/auth/google')
.then(response => {
  console.log(response);
}).catch(err => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

};

This gets routed to my authRoutes.js file.

```
/**
 * Authentication with Google.
 */
router.get('/google', passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['profile'] }));

/**
 * Redirect from Google.
 */
router.get('/auth/google/redirect', 
  passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect: '/' }),
  (req, res) => {
    // Successful authentication, redirect home.
    res.redirect('/');
  }
```

Now my passport-setup.js looks like this:

```
passport.use(
  new GoogleStrategy({
    // Options for the Google strategy.
    clientID: keys.google.clientID,
    clientSecret: keys.google.clientSecret,
    callbackURL: '/auth/google/redirect',
  }, () => {
    // Passport callback function. TODO
  })
```

Now what's the problem? Well everytime I click the button I get this lovely exception:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=[...]' (redirected from 'http://localhost:8080/api/auth/google') from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

YET, if I drop make the same request via the browser directly or from Postman, I'm successfully able to get the Google sign in page? What am I doing wrong?

Before you ask, yes I am ignoring CORS in my app.js:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "*")
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
```

Comment: Did you register your localhost URL with Google?

Comment: If I've read the error message right, it's google's URL which is blocking the request, not your app, so your CORS settings in your app are not going to help.